# Should PDFs for on-screen reading be split into pages (with a "real" paper size)?

Tags: usability, readability, documentation, pdf, document-design

Downloadable PDFs are not a good format for on-screen reading and should be avoided, but sometimes there's nothing we can do about it. That's my case now: I have to design a PDF for on-screen reading (of what should really be a landing page).

All PDFs I've ever interacted with have "real" paper sizes and are split in multiple pages accordingly. Is there a reason for this besides making them print-friendly?

Can I create a one page long sheet pdf or can it be problematic in some way?

Thanks!

Comment: The efficacy of the requirement may be suspect, but if the requirement *is* a PDF displayed on screen then break it into pages. Because...WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, having a single large PDF page is necessary, particularly when a craftsman is working with a template. For instance, an embroiderer working on a large cross-stitch pattern on a tablet needs to be able to zoom in and easily navigate within the chart. This is because, as opposed to having multiple pages, which would require flipping and scrolling to find the section being worked on, a single large page allows for a seamless workflow.